# How to test deletionGracePeriodSeconds in pod templates with K8S

Tags: templates, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-pod

I am new to k8s. I would like to test the deletionGracePeriodSeconds feature.
Documentation says :

> deletionGracePeriodSeconds (integer) : Number of seconds allowed for this object to gracefully terminate before it will be removed from the system. Only set when deletionTimestamp is also set.

I guess that if the pod terminates nicely, the feature does not apply.

So, How can I make the pod "reject" deletion in order to see how this feature works? Does it work for deletion by command :

```
kubectl delete pod mypod
```

or only with scheduled deletion with "deletionTimestamp"

Here is how I tried to do it (via the trap command) but it does not seem to work :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  deletionGracePeriodSeconds: 10
  deletionTimestamp: 2020-08-05T14:40:00Z
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: nginx
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
    - trap "" 2 3 15 20 | sleep 600
```

Thanks in advance
Abdelghani

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are asking about `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`, please correct me if I'm mistaken and I'll edit accrodingly.

The `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` is the time between Kubernetes sends the `SIGTERM` signal to the pod main process (`PID 1`) until it sends the `SIGKILL` signal, which abruptly kills the process (and subsequently, the pod itself).

`SIGTERM` signal is meant to be interpreted by the process, and it should start a "Graceful Shutdown" - stop receiving new tasks and finish the work on existing ones. If the process in your pod needs more than 30 seconds for this procedure (let's say you're running a worker which process each task in 2 minutes), you'd want to extend the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` accordingly.

So you can't make the pod "reject" the deletion, but your process can either ignore the `SIGTERM` signal, and then after the period configured in `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` it'll be killed abruptly, or it may be that your process needs more time to gracefully shutdown (and in that case, you'd want to increase `

Comment: thank you hilsenrat for your unswer. So If I understand it right, if I set terminationGracePeriodSeconds to 30 AND set deletionTimestamp and make the container in the pod execute : trap "" 15 | sleep 600 then it will not be killed immediately when I execute kubectl delete mypod. But this does not happen and the pod is immediately terminted. I updated my question with the yml file.

Comment: deletionTimestamp and deletionGracePeriod are only relevant when using [finalizers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#finalizers). If you will not add/edit this parameters, and tweak only the terminationGracePeriod, or keep it at it default state (30 seconds), it will work as you expect.

Comment: `metadata.deletionGracePeriodSeconds` is initialized when you delete a pod. The init value defaultly comes from `spec.terminationGracePeriodSeconds` field, but could be overrided by `kubectl delete pod <name> --grace-period <seconds>`